# Deserialising 2D Array from JSON using Java/Jackson libraries throws exception

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I want to deserialise a 2D array of Strings into a `String[][]` field using the following JSON and pojo.

**Pojo Code**

```
public class DataProcess {

    public enum Command {INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE}
    private Command command;
    private String table;
    private String[] columns;
    private String[][] values;

    public String[] getColumns() {return columns;}
    public void setColumns(String[] columns) {this.columns = columns;}
    public String[][] getValues() {return values;}
    public void setValues(String[][] values) {this.values = values;}
    public Command getCommand() {return command;}
    public void setCommand(Command command) {this.command = command;}
    public String getTable() {return table;}
    public void setTable(String table) {this.table = table;}
}
```

**JSON to deserialise**

```
...

    "preTestData": [{
      "columns": ["tracking_id"],
      "values": [["AAAAAAA"]],
      "command": "DELETE",
      "table": "my_table"
    }],

...
```

When I run the deserialising code I get the following exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize         
instance of java.lang.String[][] out of START_OBJECT token
at [Source: {
   "name": "Basic create shipment request",
  "preTestData": [{
    "columns": ["tracking_id"],
    "values": [["AAAAAAA"]],
    "command": "DELETE",
    "table": "my_table"
  }],
```

For further investigation I wrote the reverse serialising code and printed out the resulting JSON.

This was the output:

```
...
    "preTestData": [{
        "columns": ["tracking_id"],
        "values": [["AAAAAAA"]],
        "command": "DELETE",
        "table": "my_table"
    }],
...
```

Looks identical - but anyway I pasted that JSON output over the problematic part of my JSON to be deserialised.

I got exactly the same error.

Does anyone know why this error is occurring or how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the exception is being thrown. As you stated - the reverse operation produces exactly the same JSON.

However I do have a work-around solution which is a bit clunky but will get you moving forward.

My work-around is to replace the `String[][]` type with `Object`.

```
private Command command;
private String table;
private String[] columns;
private Object values;    // was String[][]
```

Run your deserialisation code and you will see that the Jackson library represents the 2D array with the type `List<List<String>>`. So all that's needed is a cast and you can then access all the elements.

```
List<List<String>> values = (List<List<String>>) object.getValues();
```

I did try using `List<List<String>>` to directly replace `String[][]` in the target object, but that threw a similar exception.

Comment: Thank you - that worked for me.

I also tried using `List<List<String>>` directly and still got an exception. I forgot to mention that on my original post.

Answer (score -1):

use code below to convert 2D String array:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String[][] asArray = mapper.readValue(jsonString, String[][].class);
```

but for your question Jackson does all things without effort and any problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String json = "[{\"columns\": [\"tracking_id\"]," +
            "\"values\": [[\"AAAAAAA\"]],\n" +
            "\"command\": \"DELETE\",\n" +
            "\"table\": \"my_table\"\n" +
            "}],";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    DataProcess[] dataProcess = mapper.readValue(json, DataProcess[].class);
    System.out.println("asArray = " + dataProcess);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I see this code will work for an object that is only a 2D array and nothing else. However, my 2D array is within another object.